# how to transform dangling participle

Tags: dangling-participle

*Hiking the trail, the birds chirped loudly.*

This is the example of the so called Dangling Participle. To improve this sentence it is recommended to transform it in "Hiking the trail, we heard birds chirping loudly". I would like to ask if it would be as well possible just to add the pronoun – *Our hiking the trail, the birds chirped loudly*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hiking the trail, the birds chirped loudly.

is ambiguous. Most readers would assume *someone* was hiking on a trail and heard birds, however, the sentence could also be interpreted to mean

> The birds were hiking on the trail and chirping loudly.

Adding **our**, though grammatically correct, is not very useful, since doesn't add anything to the connection of "hiking" and "chirping" which is the intent of the original passage

> **While we were** hiking the trail, the birds chirped loudly.
>   **During our** hiking the trail, the birds chirped loudly.

might be better.

Comment: 'During our hiking the trail' is rather clumsy; the first of the two is examples is much better.

Comment: Yeah, I know, "while" is an easy one and I was trying to think of different example and could only come up with "during".